# praw reddit bot responding multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, praw

i am trying to make a reddit bot with praw but it responds to the same comment multiple times.

here is my code:

```
keyphrases = ["test","test2","test3"]

for comment in subreddit.stream.comments(skip_existing=True):
    for keyphrase in keyphrases:
        if keyphrase in comment.body:
            try:
                comment.reply("hi")
            except:
                print("to frequent")
```

Comment: I have two suggestions for you. First, try `print(ids)`. You'll notice that all the IDs end in newline characters. If a comment has the ID `abc123`, when read from the file with `.readlines()` it will show up as `abc123\n`. You could try stripping this whitespace off, or better yet…

Comment: You don't actually need any of this file stuff, because PRAW can handle this for you. If you do `for comment in subreddit.stream.comments(skip_existing=True)`, then PRAW will only give you comments posted since the loop started, which means that you'll never get duplicates. Then you don't need to do anything with the text file. Btw, you can check out [the documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/subredditstream.html#praw.models.reddit.subreddit.SubredditStream.comments) for more information. I hope this helps!

Comment: @jarhill0 although skip_existing helped, the bot does still (rarely) start responding to the same comment over and over, only stopping when i close the script, i updated the post to show my current code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when a comment has multiple keyphrases in it. According to this code, we'll check for the first keyphrase, then reply, then in the next iteration of the loop we'll check for the second keyphrase, and reply again, and so on.

If you only want one reply even when there are multiple keywords in the comment, you can `break` out of the loop when you find the first keyword match:

```
for keyphrase in keyphrases:
    if keyphrase in comment.body:
        try:
            comment.reply("hi")
            break
        except:
            print("too frequent")
```

The [`break` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) exits out of a loop without performing any more iterations.